# Es correcto tener el script de ajax en el mismo formulario del html?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hola soy nuevo en ajax y quiero saber si es correcta la forma de trabajarla. Tengo el script de ajax en el mismo html o debo tenerlo en un documento aparte?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>insertar datos con ajax</title>
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="frmajax" method="POST">
  <label>Nombre</label>
  <p></p>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
  <p></p>
  <label>apellido</label>
  <p></p>
  <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">
  <p></p>
  <label>Usuario</label>
  <p></p>
  <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario">
  <p></p>
  <label>password</label>
  <p></p>
  <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
  <p></p>
  <button id="btnguardar">Guardar datos</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnguardar').click(function(){
   var datos=$('#frmajax').serialize();
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"insertar.php",
    data:datos,
    success:function(r){
     if(r==1){
      alert("agregado con exito");
     }else{
      alert("Fallo el server");
     }
    }
   });

   return false;
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: de cualquiera de los 2 modos va a funcionar, no existe una regla a seguir al respecto; separar tu código en un archivo por separado y luego llamarlo mediante `scr="tu-archivo.js"` pudiera ser útil para mantener el orden y hacer mas mantenible el mismo, pero volvemos a lo mismo es cuestión de opiniones pues no hay una regla general

Answer (score 2):

Amigo si tu codigo es algo corto no hay problema ademas podrias cargar de modo asíncrono el script de jquery añadiendo

```
 {<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" async="async"></script>
```

para que cargue de manera super rapido tu formulario. 
Recuerda si insertas una hoja de estilos o un javascript dentro de tu html y es muy extenso eso no es nada recomendable pero para pruebas y webs pequeñas esta super bien ademas te ahorras el clásico problema en Google developers PageSpeed de que el javascript impide la visualización.

Comment: con que sustentas tu afirmación de **super rapido** ?

Comment: además que JavaScript impida la visualización es solo si por ejemplo dentro del HTML, este código estuviera declarado en la cabecera por ejemplo

Comment: Al ser un simple formulario sin imagenes ni complementos solo se carga el html pero al llevar el jquery disminuye la velocidad de carga porque al ir dentro del html se espera hasta que se descargue y hasta entonces visualizas la web al cargarlo en modo asíncrono simplemente carga el html basico y luego el jquery lo que optimiza el tiempo de carga o me equivoco?

Comment: vuelvo a replantear la pregunta: ¿que mediciones nos puedes compartir? o pruebas para sustentar dicha afirmación? tu respuesta es válida si la acompaña un benchmark por ejemplo

Comment: http://datatest.html-5.me/ @shadow revisa la web ahi puse el mismo código de modo asíncrono y síncrono verifica con pagespeed de google y ahi tienes mi respuesta la cual fui claro te ahorras el clásico problema de Page Speed.

Comment: De modo síncrono tenes 76/100 en moviles y 97/100 en ordenador  pero de modo asíncrono tenes 100/100 en ambas y mi estimado amigo recuerda que en base a esos puntajes google define que tan buena es tu web para su motor de busqueda.

Answer (score 1):

No está mal para pruebas o proyectos sencillos, pero para algunas cosas más grandes es necesario que tu código sea separado y no se convierta en Spaguetti (una combinación de código de diferentes lenguajes en un mismo archivo) por eso es importante tener en cuenta algunas arquitecturas web al momento de trabajar, te anexo una página con información al respecto espero y te sirvan.

https://www.arquitecturajava.com/arquitecturas-web-y-su-evolucion/

Saludos

Comment: 2 cosas, tu respuesta es mas un comentario, segundo poner enlaces es de baja calidad y un extra, tu argumento es debatible entonces no es bueno responder preguntas basadas en opiniones

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo tomaré mucho en cuenta